# Laravel Livewire always errors at mount but die dumps fine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

What seems to be the problem: Livewire mount seems to error out on me but diedumps fine.
Steps to Reproduce: Just a simple rendering the route parameter to the commponent.
Are you using the latest version of Livewire: Yes 2.4

My route

```
Route::get('{name}', Counter::class);
```

My component blade file

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <button wire:click="increment"></button>
  <h1>{{$name}}</h2>
</div>
```

My component class

```
    public $count = 0;
    public $name;
    public function mount($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
```

it then gives me this error 
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $name ]] in class App\Http\Livewire\Counter (View: E:\wamp64\www\test\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)

Comment: What happend when

```public $name = '';```

Comment: Same, i'm using inline components, but when I change it to a full page it works, don't know why, my goal is to get the param in an inline component.

Comment: How are you using your inline component?

Comment: Yeap, for example, looks like a full page component

Comment: ```
  @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <livewire:counter />
  </div>
  @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Comment: @kgcusi

Show code of component

Comment: `<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $name = '';
    public $count = 0;

    public function mount($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function increment()
    {
        $this->count++;
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.counter');
    }
}`

Comment: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#parameters

`<livewire:counter :name="$name" />`

Comment: Do you follow the instructions at this link? 

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components#route-params

Answer (score 1):

Route parameters will be passed to full page components by Livewire, however, when calling inline components you need to pass the required properties, they are not automatically resolved.

```
<livewire:counter :name="$name" />
```

Comment: This gives me an error of `undefined variable : name`, my goal is to pass the params to the inline component, my inline component is inside the layouts/app.blade.php file.

Comment: You need to pass `$name` to `app.blade.php` from which ever controller renders it.

Comment: Ohh so I need to pass down all the necessary starting from the `app.blade.php` file?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide the `$name` if you're not using a full page component with route parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `@livewire('counter')` you do not need to pass the name parameter because the blade engine already does, but when you use the blade component you have to pass the name parameter `<livewire:counter :name="$name" />`